# Which MIDi interface to get for more channels?

Tags: midi, windows, gear

I own Roland UM-4 that was a good MIDI interface but it's not working with 64-bit windows or similar so I've bought a cheap 1-channel plexgear MIDI interface which is not enough when I now also own the Cyclone Analogic TT303, I want at least 2 channels MIDI and preferrably 3 or 4 channels like the UM 4 has but it's incompatible with 64-bit os.

Can you tell me what I could use to buy and whether I also need a sound card? My gear is

Roland TR909
Cyclone TT303
Mackie ProFX8 
Graphite 49 MIDI controller
Roland Juno 60 
Cubase + Reason + FL + WIndows 7

### Update

I looked at a midisport 4-channel interface for abt USD 120 that seemed good. I also bought a second 1-channel plexgear interface to quickly get the connection I need from the local radio shack. Then I also might get a better soundcard since the soundcard I own today is cheap and bad - the Sony Vaio internal soundcard and a plexgear external usb soundcard. I have put my money in the instruments (Roland TR 909, Cyclone TT303, Roland Juno 60) and I will now wire everything so that we can make techno.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply use more than one midi adapter?

Comment: It may be possible to install a 32-bit windows virtual machine to use to communicate with the device and then use some sort of midi-over-lan to communicate between the 32-bit guest OS and the 64-bit host OS. I am unsure about latency in this scenario. I have used this method with still-camera software, but nothing real-time

Comment: @AJHenderson I've done what you mentioned and I've installed 2 1-channel plexgear midi adapter. I also looked at a 4-channel midisport interface for about USB 120 so it's no major studio investment like a new instrument had been if I want something with less wire and rack mountable. The MIDI adapters I use today are 2 plexgear 1-channel USB MIDI adapters and 1 is connected to the Roland TR909 and the other is connected to the Cyclone TT303. They can playback independendly and control from cubase but I haven't gotten them to listen to my MIDI keyboard (Samosonn Graphite 49) yet but I will.